# in android only push some part of view instead whole view, while open keyboard

Tags: android

I want to push some part of screen to up instead whole view

for example below is the screen

[image]

When I click on edit text in that Only centerview which is scrollview want to pushup, the **title bar and below sentinal button should remain same**

instead right now

[image]

I have read many post related issue

also I have put

```
mActivity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

I have also put in menifest file

```
   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" >
```

General overview of design is

```
   Activity
    -----LinearLayout-------             Weightsum(20)
         Title Bar(TextView)------    weight - 3
         Fragment                               weight - 15
         -----ScrollView-------        
                    <LinearLayout>
                      --List_Item 1
                      --List_Item 2
                      --List_Item 3
                      --List_Item 4
                    <LinearLayout>
         BottomBar(TextView)----------        weight - 2
```

but nothing is happening

Comment: Is your title bar in `ScrollView`?

Comment: No @PiyushGupta , only center-part is in scrollview

Comment: Try to put your title bar in scrollview

Answer (score 2):

put that view that you want to be adujsted in scrollview  and enable it when keyboard comes up

use requestfocus on the edittext .. so nothing gets ajdusted and since its is scrollview the edittext only comes to editing

Comment: I have already put centerview in ScrollView but still not working

Comment: use requestfocus on the edittext .. so nothing gets ajdusted and since its is scrollview the edittext only comes to editing